# Sails.js Single Page Application (SPA) — redirect all missing/unused routes to a single controller action

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, single-page-application

I'm developing a single page application (SPA) using Sails.js as a backend. All I want is to redirect all routes to a single controller action.

However, when I do the following:

```js
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  'GET *': 'MainController.application'
};
```

All requests are getting redirected to my application route, even for static files like CSS/JavaScript, etc. Is there an easy way to fallback to my application route when there is no other means to handle it?

I want:

1. All static files to be served directly (JS, CSS, HTML partials)
2. All specific routes to be handled as is
3. In other case redirect to a single entry-point controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thorough re-reading of the docs I've found a `skipAssets` route parameter.

Here's my new configuration:

```js
// config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  'GET *': {
    controller: 'MainController',
    action: 'application',
    skipAssets: true
  }
};
```

Looks like it's working as required.

Comment: Keep in mind also that in the `config/routes.js` file, order matters--so always put your more dynamic routes at the bottom, or else the more specific routes won't get matched.

Comment: Good info sgress454 I've been caught out by this in the past. An easy one to forget.

Comment: Works nice for .css and .js, but for sockets and RESTful URLs, they all get redirected to Index.html (or MainController.action, etc). I wish there was a better way to do this.